# Meaning of "Autant faire"?

Tags: grammaire, sens, expressions-idiomatiques, locutions

> "...comme nous devrons y goûter devant les romains, autant faire un bon potage."

I don't really understand that grammatically. I interpret the sentence to mean something to the effect of "Since we'll have to eat this in front of the Romans, may as well make a good soup." But really not sure about that *autant faire* at all.

Comment: Translation: "Since we'll have to taste it in front of the Romans, best make a good soup."

Comment: I wonder if it's a colloquial version of [autant que faire se peut](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/autant_que_faire_se_peut)?

Comment: @rolfedh No, “autant que faire se peut” is a completely different, archaic, construction. It's an idiom, otherwise the way to say it in modern French would be “autant qu'on peut le faire”.

Comment: Did you read that in an Asterix book ? I'm fairly certain this "potage" is a fake magic potion...

Comment: Yes, you're right! But of course I knew that. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est un idiome, et tu l'as interprété correctement. La construction anglaise est parallèle, en fait : c'est une comparaison à laquelle il manque le point de comparaison, et le sujet peut être omis lorsqu'il est impersonnel ou évident. En français, quand on omet le sujet, le verbe est à l'infinitif. On peut aussi avoir un verbe conjugué au subjonctif.

> Autant que nous fassions un bon potage.

Le *Trésor de la langue française* ([autant](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/autant) I.A.3) l'explique comme la locution *autant vaut* (« autant vaut X que Y ») dans laquelle on omet la proposition comparative et le verbe *valoir*. En fait les deux sont presque tout le temps omis.

> Autant [vaut] faire un bon potage [qu'un mauvais].
>   Autant [vaut-il] que nous fassions un bon potage [qu'un mauvais].

La locution « mieux vaut … » ou « il vaut mieux » est plus courante et a à peu près le même sens, mais en plus fort (« autant vaut … » signifie en fait « … est un peu mieux »). Après *mieux*, on n'omet pas le verbe *valoir*.

> Il vaut mieux que nous fassions un bon potage, puisque nous devrons y goûter.
>   Mieux vaut faire un bon potage, puisqu'on devra y goûter.

Answer (score 1):

It means "... we might as well ..."

So:
"...comme nous devrons y goûter devant les romains, autant faire un bon potage."

"... since we have to taste it in front of the Romans we might as well make it a good soup."